# Customization mistakes and changing the layout type of a core page configuration xml

Tags: magento2, layout

In the official M2 docs we have this quote

> Changing handle inheritance. For example, you should not change the page type parent handle.

Pulled from here [M2 Frontend Dev Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html#override-mistake)

By this I understand you should not make changes like 1column -> 3columns. If this means something else please correct me. If I'm right, what are the reasons for which this is bad practice?

What is the recommended way to change the layout of a page? If this is considered a bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

> Example: Change the layout of Advanced Search page from default “1-column” to “2-column with left bar”. To do this, extend catalogsearch_advanced_index.xml in your theme by adding the following layout:

```
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
...
</page>
```